# Can I update various items in an Immutable List in a React/Redux App

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

On submitting a form with some updated values, I need to update the state to reflect these changes, but I am new to Immutable.js and am unsure how to do so.

Is it possible to pass a function as a 2nd argument to set or update to update values based on certain criteria.

I have a function which receives state and an array of objects called values. The data in values looks like this:

```
[
  {
    key: 'name',
    value: 'fred'
  },
  {
    key: 'height',
    value: '201'
  },
  {
    key: 'weight',
    value: '78'
  }
]
```

I need to map over this data, and the state list, and update the corresponding values in the state list with the values array.

How can I do this. I have put together a function which the Reducer calls to update the state with the new data, but unsure exactly how to get the end result

```
 function updateValue(state, values = []) { 
  const items = state.get('items').map((i) => {
    const key = i.get('key');

    values.map(v => {
      if (v.key === key) {
        return state.update('value', v.value);
      }
    })
  });

  return state.update('items', /* Can I use a function here to replace the code above.. to update all of the items in the state List that correspond to the items in the measurements array (which have new values) */);
}
```

Thank you very much.

**Update**
Tried the following, but getting the error: `Expected [K, V] tuple: i`

```
function updateValue(state, values = []) { 
  const items = state.get('items').map((i) => {
    const key = i.get('key');

    values.map(v => {
      if (v.key === key) {
        return state.update('value', v.value);
      }
    })
  });

  return state.update('items', items);
}
```

More details on the error from Immutable:

```
function validateEntry(entry) {
    if (entry !== Object(entry)) {
      throw new TypeError('Expected [K, V] tuple: ' + entry);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You're getting that error because when you `map` over an instance of `Map` the mapper function takes a key value pair, so something like `map((k,v)  =>  ....)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'merge' to return new object:

return state.merge({
        items: values,
      });

Comment: Thanks Alexander, tried this and updated question with the code I used. Getting an error.